# Large Factorial Divisibility

Tags: divisibility, factorial

I need some help regarding factorials. Say I have a number like $2012!$. I want to test whether it is divisible by $100$. How would I do this? I already know how to use Stirling's approximation, but want to know if there is an even better way.

Comment: Yes, there is a much better way: $n!$ is divisible by every $k\in[1,n]$, hence $2012!$ is divisible by $100\in[1,2012]$. In its current state, this question looks rather pointless, since the answer is obvious and immediate (kinda like asking how to tell whether or not $100\leq2012$).

Comment: @barakmanos Can you please elaborate a little more?

Comment: More than I already have??? Not really. Do you know the actual definition of "$!$" (aka *factorial*)?

Comment: @barakmanos I read an older comment that was kind of short. I do know what a factorial is. I don't know why the whole thing didn't load. But yes. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to write out $2012!$ it would look something like this:

$$2012!=1\times2\times3\times4\times\cdots\times99\times100\times101\times\cdots\times2011\times2012$$

Note that is is multiplied by 100 (and lots of other numbers) so it is divisible by 100.